# How to use variable from other class (captured QRcode) as reference in .getReference().child()?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
 Intent intentt = getIntent(); //get data from QRScannerActivity
    String resultQR = intentt.getStringExtra("resultData");
    try{
        if(resultQR != null){
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(resultQR);
            mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String bm_bertulis_marks =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_marks").getValue(String.class);
                    String bm_bertulis_grade =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_grade").getValue(String.class);

                    bmBertulisMarks.setText(bm_bertulis_marks);
                    bmBertulisGrade.setText(bm_bertulis_grade);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As I captured the data from QR code scanner, I use intent to pass the data into this Activity, but when I run the app nothing appeared and the activity stopped. So i guess the variable `resultQR` cannot be use in `child()` Is there any solution?

```
Process: com.example.mainmenuapp, PID: 31269
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:425)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:216)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:203)
    at com.example.mainmenuapp.StudentResultActivity$1.onDataChange(StudentResultActivity.java:73)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
```

My logcat error >>

Comment: Is resultQR not null?

Comment: Add ur database, add a log to check if it is entering the if

Comment: If the activity crashes there's a error message and stack trace in the logcat output of your app. Please find those, and add them to your question.

Comment: not null since its scanned from my QR scanner activity. And yes my database connection works if i directly using the child name from my database @PeterHaddad

Comment: yeah just posted it @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You are retrieving a long value from ur database, but u are using String

Comment: @HamiziMazlan if the answer helped you please mark it as correct thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
String bm_bertulis_marks =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_marks").getValue(String.class);
String bm_bertulis_grade =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_grade").getValue(String.class);
```

Into this:

```
Long bm_bertulis_marks =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_marks").getValue(Long.class);
Long bm_bertulis_grade =dataSnapshot.child("bm_bertulis_grade").getValue(Long.class);
```